# Which chapter of the manga does Season 4 of Nanatsu No Taizai anime start?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

If I want to start reading the manga of Nanatsu no Taizai by the chapter season 4 of the anime start (so I can get spoilers of what's going to happen in this season of the anime), which chapter should I start reading the manga?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long though I read the manga of this anime. But as far as I remember in the beginning of the first episode of new season Ban was in Purgatory. So in accordance with the manga, it should be either Chapter 267 or 268, sorry I don't remembered the numbered. But title was **From Purgatory**. If you have watched 1st episode a little, you will understand in manga where the scenes matches the anime.

Comment: You should start on chapter 268